# How to force browser language settings to English?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application, with two files for languages English and French, I want the application to always load in English. But when the browser language settings are in French, the french version is loaded. How can I force the language to be always English despite the browser setting?

Comment: witch library do you use to add translate in angular?

Comment: Are you using ngx-translate? If so, i'd recomment reading their readME, as it has an example that will suit your needs:

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core